QOpenGLWindow: how to prevent it from getiing (keyboard) focus by click
I'm contributing to a Qt app which recently got embedded QOpenGLWindows for certain special graphics.
Issue was that these windows received keyboard focus when being clicked, while the focus should remain in the QWidget that currently had focus.
With Qt 5 it was sufficient to set the Qt::Tooltip flag for all QOpenGLWindows.
With Qt 6 however, that doesn't work anymore on Linux (with Qt 6.2.3).
(and neither do the Qt::Tool, Qt::SplashScreen or Qt::SubWindow)
The FocusIn event can also not be catched with a event(QEvent*) override.
Does someone know what exactly has been changed in Qt 6 that causes this behaviour?
Or, even better, how I could achieve the "focus in block"?

Have you considered setting the Qt::WA_X11DoNotAcceptFocus window flag?

Thanks @musicamente, meanwhile I discovered the Qt::WindowFlag Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus which seems to do the trick on all platforms.
Just set that flag in the constructor, done.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum
